# Launch App from eMail with URL-Sheme

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-urlsheme

Hello I have a custom URL to open an app with a link. It works in the browser. But I want to send an email that another user can click the link in the email and the app will be started. Does anybody know a solution?

It is not possible to send an email with the link (myApp://). It always shows the the link as blank text.

Or does anyone know another solution to transfer data between an app to a other users app?

Comment: "... shows the line as blank text"? Are you hardcoding the email body or using a template? HTML email or plaintext (and relying on the email client to recognize it)? Please show the code for the body and any "fill in the blank" code that you might be using.

Comment: Hi you are right. With a template it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write the link in `href` html tag

i.e. `<a href="myApp://...">open my app</a>`

another solution is to try to add any text after the double slash i.e.  `myApp://open`

Comment: @user3678815 I tried to make it work and it only works if I add any text after the double slash i.e.  `myApp://open`